# Where is the code controlling the red circle part output in magento?

Tags: php, magento

[image]

Where is the source code controlling the red circle part output in magento? if i want to remove it, how do i do?

Comment: Downvoted for "This question does not show any research effort"

Answer (score 3):

To find that out, go to your Admin.  Go to Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer.  Change your scope to Website and change Template Path Hints to "Yes".  Now on your front-end you'll see exactly which template file is generating that section.

[image]